# Django Aggragate query issue in template

Tags: python, django, templates, aggregate

Here's my code:

**MODEL**

```
class compilation (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    slot = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    slotpergroup = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(song,related_name="slotsongs", null=True, blank=True)

class song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.FileField(upload_to='static/canzoni', validators=[validate_file_audio])
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(group)


class group(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genr = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    avatar = models.FileField(upload_to='static/logogruppi', validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

**VIEW**

```
c = {}
compilation = compilation.objects.all()
c.update({'compilation': compilation })
return render_to_response('compilation.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**TEMPLATE compilation.html**

```
{% for cd in compilation %}

    {{ cd.title }}<br/> 

    PLAYLIST
    {% for song in cd.songs.all %}
        {{ song.title | capfirst }}<br/>
        {% for g in song.groups.all %}
            {{ g | capfirst }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}


    {% for gr in user.group_set.all %}    

    --> here my problem, I need something like this: 
    var = song.objects.filter(groups=gr).filter(slotsongs=cd).count()
    if cd.slotpergropu <= var:    
        print: "all slots are busy for this group"  <--

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

I need to show for each compilation, for each user's group, if there are available slots or if someone of his group took all own available slot yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django **enforces MVC framework by not implicitly allowing any Buseness logic in Templates.**

By standards **these kind of things should be done in Views** and the result should be passed as context to Templates.

But, **if it is so necessary** to Make this query in the Templates then you can use **Template tags** for this purpose like following:

Use **Assginment tag here**:

```
{% load songs_tags %}
{% get_songs_for_group gr cd  as var %}
```

Create template tag file

```
### templatetags/songs_tags.py ###
@register.assignment_tag
def get_songs_for_groups(group, collection):
 return song.objects.filter(groups=group).filter(slotsongs=collection).count()
```

See documentation for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags

Comment: Yes I know that is better use the view but in this case I haven't found a simple way to make it. I'll thank you if you have some suggestions. In all case thank you very much this custom tag works!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't call a function that requires parameters in a template. You have to assemble what you need in `views.py`, write a template tag or filter instead. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags) to learn more about it.